# Incorporation of Dialogflow CX Agent on Pepper Robot using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, pepper, dialogflow-cx

I would like to implement a Dialogflow *CX* Chatbot on Pepper Robot using Android Studio. I find tutorials and repos - but all of them deal with version ES. Is there any way to do the same with CX? Is there a repo or tutorial available?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into using the Dialogflow CX API? While there are only client libraries for Java, NodeJS and Python, you can always access the API with REST. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3-overview) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api).

Comment: Thank you! I will check that!

Answer (score 0):

Teresa answered in the comments:

> Have you looked into using the Dialogflow CX API? While there are only
> client libraries for Java, NodeJS and Python, you can always access
> the API with REST. See here and here.

Answer (score 0):

There are no official Dialogflow documentations for integrating a Dialogflow CX agent on Pepper Robot using Android Studio.

For any unsupported platforms, if they provide developer tools, you can create your own implementation and make calls to Dialogflow's API. You can check the [Interaction with APIs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api) documentation for some [examples](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api#detect_intent) showing how to call the detectIntent method.

You can also check Dialogflow’s [Client Libraries and APIs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference) and see which one of these will work on your use case.